# How to create a list taking values out of specific indexes of other list and then do a sort?

Tags: tcl

Consider listA = `a b c d` and listB = `19 22 7 1`. Is it possible to create a third list like
listC = `{a 19} {b 22} {c 7} {d 1}` and then sort listC based on values of listB?
Sorted ListC could be `{d 1} {c 7} {a 19} {b 22}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Merging Two Lists

Merging the lists is just:

```
set listC [lmap a $listA b $listB {list $a $b}]
```

If you have 8.5 (or before) then that becomes:

```
set listC {}
foreach a $listA b $listB {
    lappend listC [list $a $b]
}
```

but if you have 8.5 or before, you're recommended to work on upgrading to 8.6; 8.5 is only really on security support now.

### Sorting the Merged List

The `lsort` command has the `-index` option for exactly this case:

```
# Use -integer for integer sorting, of course
set sortedC [lsort -integer -index 1 $listC]
```

The option is supported on all supported versions of Tcl.